# How to directly use "gettype($val)" in a table

Tags: php, html, string

I have developed a table to list all the $_SESSION variables being used.
The code below works, but it involves designating a temporary variable.

```
$temp= gettype($val);
echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$temp</td><td>$val</td></tr>";
```

If possible, I would like to skip designating the temporary variable so that the code would work similar to the non-working example below:

```
echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>gettype($val)</td><td>$val</td></tr>";
```

I tried various approaches to using quote marks around "gettype($val)", but to no avail.

Comment: Try this:- echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>" . gettype($val) ."</td><td>$val</td></tr>";

Comment: can't you just concatenate that

Comment: @ghost: Thanks. Concatenation worked, I still have a lot to learn concerning how to use concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place function calls in the middle of a string. There are several ways to do this. Here's an example using concatenation.

```
echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>" . gettype($val) . "</td><td>$val</td></tr>";
```